# Second spellchecker doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, nexus-4, dictionary, spell-check

I have a Nexus 4, and I'm using Google keyboard on Android 4.3.1. When I switch the keyboard language from French (the system language) to Polish, spellchecking stops. I have the polish spell-checking dictionary installed.

Suggestion works in both languages. Spell-checking works only in french.

What should I do?

I'd rather fix this problem than use another keyboard.

Comment: Looks to me you are mixing up 2 different things in your question: Auto-correction and Spell-check. Are you looking for Auto-correction (where the misspelled word is replaced) or for spell check (where the misspelled word is underlined)?

Comment: I realize my question could have been better worded. I'm looking for spell check. Suggestion works in both languages. Spell-checking only works in french, but the polish spell-checking dictionary is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the keyboard used (Android vs Google). I have fixed this by selecting [Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en) and adding there the languages I need.